# Creating a filter of tags for a blog in handlebars/endurojs

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, enduro.js

I'm creating a blog with tags, each blog entry can have multiple tags that can be filtered to show blog entries with the same tag choosen.

My problem lies when i'm filtering the results i'm not sure how to send the tag (or keyword) to another handlebar helper as a parameter, so i can show just the blog entries with the same tag.

This code gets all the tags from all blog entries:

```
<h4 class="white-color remove-margin">Tags:
      {{#blog}}
          {{#joinTags this}}
             {{#each this}}
                  <a class="badge bg-light-blue" onclick="filterBlogEntries('{{this}}')">#{{this}}</a>
              {{/each}}
          {{/joinTags}}
      {{/blog}}
</h4>
```

The `filterBlogEntries` right now doesn't do nothing, only prints the parameter that is sent. That one parameter is the one i need to filter all the blog entries.

So far, i list all the blog post like this:

```
 {{#blog}}
       {{#each_upto this 6}}
                            <article>
                                  <li class="blog-list__item">   
                                    <div class="blog-entry">
                                        <img class="blog-entry__img" src="{{blog_entry.blog_img}}">
                                        <h4 class="blog-tag">
                                            {{#each blog_entry.blog_tag}}
                                                <span class="badge bg-light-blue">#{{this}}</span>
                                            {{/each}}
                                        </h4>
                                        <h3 class="highlight center-text remove-margin">{{blog_entry.blog_title}}</h3>
                                        <h4 class="center-text remove-margin">{{blog_entry.blog_subtitle}}</h4>
                                        <a class="blue-color bold center-text" onclick="showEntry( '{{blog_entry.blog_img}}','{{blog_entry.blog_tag}}','{{blog_entry.blog_title}}',   '{{blog_entry.blog_subtitle}}','{{blog_entry.blog_text}}')">Ver más</a>
                                    </div>
                               </li>                  

                            </article>
       {{/each_upto}}
  {{/blog}}
```

Now, my question is, from the function filterBlogEntries(), how i can send the tag that was chosen by the user to filter the blog entries by tag?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue lately , i add tags to the blog posts first and than to the page where will be listed, also created a new helper to list posts by tag.

My generated blogpost in **cms/generators/blog/example-post.js** looks like this

```
({
    $meta_data_expander: true,
    $meta_data_info: 'won\'t work with the temp action',
    meta_data: {
        page_title: '',
        $keywords_type: 'textarea',
        keywords: '',
        $meta_description_type: 'textarea',
        meta_description: ''
    },
    display_title: 'Example title',
    published: true,
    $date_value: '2019-01-08',
    $date_type: 'date',
    date: 'Tuesday, 08 January, 2019',
    teaser: {
        $cover_type: 'image',
        cover: '/remote/direct_uploads/1546951493_lite-feature.jpg',
        marked: 'Example endurojs generator template.',
        $marked_markdown: false,
        $marked_type: 'textarea'
    },
    main_content: {
        $content_type: 'quill',
        content: '<h1>Heading 1</h1><h2>Heading 2</h2><h3>Heading 3</h3><p>Normal</p>',
        $content_control_path: '/brick/enduro_quill/quill_control'
    },
    enable_comments: true,
    $tags_templatitator: '@@global.tags_elements',
    tags: [
        {
            project: true
        }
    ]
})
```

All the tags are added in the tags arrays.

In the page where the articles will be listed **cms/projects.js** we define the article tags that will be shown.

```
({
    $meta_data_expander: true,
    $meta_data_info: 'won\'t work with the temp action',
    meta_data: {
        page_title: '',
        $keywords_type: 'textarea',
        keywords: '',
        $meta_description_type: 'textarea',
        meta_description: ''
    },

    tags: [
            {project: true}
          ]
})
```

We register a new handlebar helper

**assets/hbs_helpers/blog_list_by_tag.js**

```
var _ = require('lodash')
var Promise = require('bluebird')

var pagelist_generator = enduro.api.pagelist_generator

enduro.templating_engine.registerHelper('blog_list_by_tag', function (tags, options) {

    var pages
    return pagelist_generator.get_cms_list()
        .then((pagelist) => {
            var get_content_promises = []
            pages = _.chain(pagelist.structured.blog)
                .filter((o) => { return typeof o === 'object' }).value() // filter pages only

            for (page_id in pages) {
                var page = pages[page_id]

                function get_content (page) {
                    get_content_promises.push(enduro.api.flat.load(page.fullpath).then((content) => { page.content = content }))
                }

                get_content(page)
            }

            return Promise.all(get_content_promises)
        })
        .then(() => {
            pages = _.chain(pages)
                .sortBy('content.$date_value').reverse() // sort by date
                .filter((page) => { return page.content.published }) // remove unpublished              
                .filter( //filter by tag
                    (page) => {
                        var taged                       
                        _.forEach(tags, (value) =>{ return  _.findIndex(page.content.tags, value) != -1 ? taged = true : false })
                        return taged 
                    }
                )
                .value()

            return options.fn(pages)
        })
})
```

And last in the context i use the newly created helper and pass the tags as argument.

```
{{#blog_list_by_tag tags}}

    {{#each this}}
        <article class="">

            <h2>
                <a href="/blog/">{{content.display_title}}</a>
            </h2>
            <p>More post data ....</p>
        </article>
    {{/each}}

{{/blog_list_by_tag}}
```